# Output size of convolutional auto-encoder in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am doing the convolutional autoencoder tutorial written by the author of the Keras library:
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

However, when I launch exactly the same code, and analyse the network's architecture with summary(), it seems that the output size is not compatible with the input one (necessary in case of autoencoders). Here is the output of summary():

```
**____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 28, 28)     0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 16, 28, 28)    160         input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 16, 14, 14)    0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 14, 14)     1160        maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 8, 7, 7)       0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 7, 7)       584         maxpooling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 8, 3, 3)       0           convolution2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_4 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 3, 3)       584         maxpooling2d_3[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 8, 6, 6)       0           convolution2d_4[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_5 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 6, 6)       584         upsampling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 8, 12, 12)     0           convolution2d_5[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_6 (Convolution2D)  (None, 16, 10, 10)    1168        upsampling2d_2[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
upsampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)    (None, 16, 20, 20)    0           convolution2d_6[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_7 (Convolution2D)  (None, 1, 20, 20)     145         upsampling2d_3[0][0]             
====================================================================================================
Total params: 4385
____________________________________________________________________________________________________**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please notice that you are missing a `border_mode` option in pre-last convolution layer.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model

input_img = Input(shape=(1, 28, 28))

x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), border_mode='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (8, 4, 4) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

This should work fine